# (Freshplanet Facebook-ANE) How to make the login screen in-app

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, authentication, ane

I am currently using the Freshplanet Facebook-ANE and was wondering about something that is bugging me currently.

I want to implement a simple post to wall feature inside my app, and this ANE does exactly what I want, except for one thing. When I do the actual post to wall dialog, it pops up just like I want it, in a WebView inside my app. The login takes me to Safari or the Facebook app if I have it installed, which is what I want to avoid.

Here's the line I'm using to open the session :

```
Facebook.getInstance().openSessionWithPublishPermissions(POST_PERMISSIONS, OnSessionOpened, true);
```

That works perfectly for posting, but takes me outside of the app.

I've tried using the same .dialog() function I use for the post, and it worked, but I can't seem to post to the wall afterwards (maybe I'm not correctly catching the access token or something)

Any help would be appreciated. I believe I've set up everything correctly on my Facebook App page, and that my AS3 project is correctly setup.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strictly stay into the app, you must use StageWebView. It's something like a wrapper of HTML page inside Flash.

First check if you are logged in (this is code from Facebook.as of FreshPlanet):

```
/** True if a Facebook session is open, false otherwise. */
public function get isSessionOpen() : Boolean
{
    if (!isSupported) return false;
    return _context.call('isSessionOpen');
}
```

If there is no session - start the web view. Otherwise - continue as usual.

You have to keep in mind that StageWebView is pretty.. how to say it.. bad is the kindest thing I could say :) You must implement your own close button, listen for url changing, etc.
You could look into Facebook AS3 SDK, which at least has some kind of 'platform' for the web view..

Good luck!